# How many jobs/stages are left in treeAggregator of spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, svd

I am running svd function on 45GB data csv with 8.9M rows in it.

So it's **8.9 hours** since my job is running

From port 8080 of master cluster dashboard following is app status.

```
| Cores | Memory per Executor| State | Duration |
| 480   | 15.0 GB | RUNNING | 8.9 h |
```

Now from jobs portal page at port 4040, i am getting the following jobs:

```
|Job Id | Description | Submitted | Duration | Stages: Succeeded/Total | Tasks (for all stages): Succeeded/Total |

| 1204 | treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:93 | xxx | 26 s | 2/2 | 501/501
| 1203 | treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:93 | xxx | 26 s | 2/2 | 501/501
....
....
| 14 | treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:93 | xxx | 26 s | 2/2 | 501/501
```

Also from Logs of the spark-submit (i have restricted it to WARN) I am getting the following in logs:

```
[Stage 2377:===================================================>(478 + 2) / 480]
```

The function that i am running is the RowMatrix computeSvd function, So my question is that i want to estimate the total time remaining to complete the whole process ? 
I know that each treeAggregator job is taking 26 second but i don't know how much jobs are left to complete this process ?

Comment: just run the same job on much smaller sample and compare the log output to see where you are now. this looks like some sort of bottleneck or a hung up program. can you check if all your workers are indeed busy (e.g. using ganglia or just manually run top on them) or if it's just the master that has been swapping massively for the past 8 hours?

Comment: Yes, everything was working fine, And job completed on 1250 job ID, Running on smaller dataset will results less job ids. so how can i map it to big data set ?